# Nested CSS rule for active tag

Tags: html, css

This is a simple question that I'm stuck with, it should show with opacity: 1 but it doesn't. Here is my code:

CSS

```
.menu{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.menu .active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="menu"><a href="index.html" title="..."><img src="..." alt="" class="active" width="25"/></a></li>
```

According to this [site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) it should work, but it doesn't, what have I done wrong?

EDIT: I am trying to have two list images, one which is faded out, one which has the active class which fades it in (opacity 1).

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It does not appear with ```opacity: 1```

Comment: The question is what is "it"?

Comment: I think that much is obvious

Comment: You might think so, but @ಠ_ಠ and I disagree. Do you want the link to have opacity of 1? Do you want the image to have opacity of one? Something else?

Comment: Why style the `<li>`'s opacity if the only thing in it is the link and image?

Comment: The item with the active flag, the image.

Comment: Child elements cannot be more opaque than their parents, as far as I know. So you are probably at 1.0 of 0.3.

Comment: @Michael_B As far as I know you cannot make a child **less** opaque, but you can make it more opaque, can't you? Opacity is not inherited according to [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/). Edit - it apparently applies to all content within an element, but "inheritance" is the wrong term, for some reason.

Comment: @Jimmy Just an FYI, W3Schools is infamous for low quality and sometimes incorrect information. They pay a lot of money to appear at the top of Google search results. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) is much better (and a wiki, so users can edit it to improve it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opacity inheritance prevents a child element from being more opaque than the parent element.

If you are just trying to make the background color transparent you could use RGB

```
.menu
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
```

**Update From Comment**

Try this:

```
.menu img{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.menu img.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. It isn't the background, im trying to have two images in my list, one which is faded out, and one which is faded in with the active flag

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't post a code example any more specific than this, I'll base my answer on what you posted. Instead of using opacity, where children can't be more opaque than their ancestors, you can use RGBA:

```
.menu {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.menu .active {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bbhkd/)**

here you can see the image is 100% opaque and the list item 30% opaque.

Comment: I've updated my question. I want two list items, one faded out and one faded in with the active class. When I try it with yours it doesnt work but thats probably because I didnt describe it properly:http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/bbhkd/3/

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle to better answer your question based on your comment:

You can now use active class as you'd like.

Updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dfJHe/1/

HTML:

```
<li class="menu"><a href="index.html" class="active" title="...">This is active.</a></li>
<li class="menu"><a href="index.html" class="" title="...">This is not active.</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
li.menu a{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
li.menu a.active{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it isn't the hover im after I want it to default to faded out and then have an active class make it faded in.

Comment: Fixed it up for you as I better understand your question now. Take a look.